# What does 'For' mean in "For he's a jolly good fellow"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does 'For' mean in "For he's a jolly good fellow"? I hope "he's" is "he is" here? Sometimes it is difficult to understand "he's" it is "he is" or "he has".

> He was picking his way across the littered, rutted market square
>   towards it (canteen) when ragged cheers and a bellowed chorus of "**For he's a
>   jolly good fellow**" from the direction of the kopje checked him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"For" means "because" in this case. ["For He's Jolly Good Fellow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_He%27s_a_Jolly_Good_Fellow) is sung to congratulate someone for something. So it doesn't make sense to say that "he has a jolly good fellow." Saying that he "is" a jolly good fellow makes more sense.